# How does Wordpress handle URLs?

Tags: php, wordpress

I encountered this (to me) unfamilliar behavior in Wordpress.

Consider a random site using WordPress with a page called *example* with no content. This is just a page type post and not a category, tag or any sort of hierarchy. A 404 error is triggered if I append characters after the last "/":

http://example.com/example/abc

I expect that but if I only type numbers after the final "/" no 404 error is triggered. For example loading:

http://example.com/example/1123456

gets me to *example* page and the numbers are kept in the URL. The numbers have no special meaning in this case. There could be any nuber there, but I would expect it to trigger a 404 as it does on other sites.

Appending numbers to the URL on index or category pages still seems to trigger a 404, but not on posts and pages.

I am wondering wether this is an actual feature of WordPress and if so, then what is its purpose?

Comment: What is  `EXTRA_CHARACTERS `? Page/Post/Category?

Comment: @HelpingHands Its actually just characters. So if I type characters after the page slug/name in the url I get 404, but if I type numbers I get directed to the actual page with numbers left in the URL

Comment: that number is id of page/post?

Comment: what you are using is pretty permalinks consult this page https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: @HelpingHands Yes its an Id of a post. But the question is general: If I go to a url of a page with numbers appended to it, will I always get to the page that the url (without the numbers) leads to? Appending characters causes 404, but appending numbers does not. I have tested this on multiple pages that use Wordpress and it always seems to be the case, that appending numbers to a page url does not seem to cause 404 and still leads to the page itself.

Comment: Actually wordpress generates unique id for each post, it is all about permalink. When your permalink set to default then URL will be like `www.example.com/id=10` and if you set any custom permalink then it will be as per that settings. You are getting 404 because your permalink structure is not set to custom of `Post Name` , Also to apply this setting you will need to allow it via .htaccess with   `mod_rewrite`

Comment: @HelpingHands Right, but in that case should I not be getting a 404 regardless? My permalink setting now is "post-name". I append the number to a URL leading to a page post-type page to be specific. I do not get 404 regardless of what number I enter- even something like 1234568 which does not match any post id for certain as I only have 6 posts on the site now.

Comment: then it should give you 404 , try in another browser , may be some caching issue.

Comment: @HelpingHands Well- tried it on Chrome, Mozilla and Explorer on 3 different Wordpress sites. Results: If you append /[some_numbers] to a page post-type page you dont seem to trigger 404.

Comment: Then I think you will need to define rule manually via htaccess

Comment: @HelpingHands The thing is I won't- I want to exploit this so that I can display correct images if a user enters the page with that url. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is as designed.  Wordpress matches URL's through the built-in rewrite module.  You can read about it [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite).  In addition, the source code to follow what is happening with this process is located in wp-content/class-wp-rewrite.php.

The specific line that provides the behavior you are seeing is below.

```
[(.?.+?)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$] => index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]
```

This code will match on page/post-name, and any following number (this supports pagination).  However, it will not match on non-characters after the post name.  What is interesting is that even if the post does not have the specified page, it will still accept as legit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it'd an odd one, but possibly by design.

`http://ww.example.com/mypage/` **200 (expected)**

`http://ww.example.com/mypage/idontexist` **404 (expected)**

But:

`http://ww.example.com/mypage/0000` **200 (unexpected)**

I think it may have to do with how WP works with archive ID's and dates as part of the permalink structure / rewrites.

Answer (score 1):

As we all knew that WordPress works through built-in rewrite module. So it will also give you Permalinks feature for all your post you can set your permalinks through it. Let's Check out the detail here about Permalinks through WordPress based blog. Here we go with the link http://codex.wordpress.org/Introduction_to_Blogging#Pretty_Permalinks

If you want to restructure your all the URL then you need to edit this file.

```
$permalink_structure
```

The permalink structure as in the database. This is what you set on the Permalink Options page, and includes `'tags' like %year%, %month% and %post_id%.`

For more detail about the permalink structure you can go through this link. 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite